# How does a user subscribe to a group with GCC?

Tags: blocks

I have the Groups, Communities and Co (GCC) module installed [7.x-1.0-beta2] but I cannot find a way for an authenticated user to subscribe themselves to a group. I have moved the 'GCC Subscription block' so that it's in the sidebar but whatever I do it's still not visible to any user. Has anyone else run into this, probably very simple, issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you add the GCC Subscription block to the sidebar, It will not show. The only time it shows up is if a user is subscribed to a group. And then the block shows up with the unsubscribe button.

That's not true.

Here are the basic steps to make the subscription block work :

1. Enable GCC, GCC Context Detection, GCC Node, GCC Block
2. Go to admin/config/gcc/permissions and make sure NON MEMBER has the "Subscribe" permission
3. Go to admin/config/gcc/context, check everything and save.
4. Place the GCC Subscription block where you want.
5. Create a group.
6. Go to your group page with another user and you will see the subscription block

Comment: Thanks. Under the Context tab of GCC Configuration I hadn't enabled the following options 'Entity Detectors - Node - Allow to detect node entity' and 'Context Detectors - Group - Determine context by checking if the current entity is a group'. Works now